# converting coffee script to javascript - simple extend

Tags: javascript, inheritance, coffeescript

I have some coffee script -

```
class Zoo.CollectionView extends Zoo.View

  _set_element_attributes: ->
    @$el.data(view: this)
    @$el.addClass('collection')
    return unless @collection?
    @$el.attr('data-name': @collection.collection_name)
    @$el.attr('data-variant': @variant) if @variant?
    @$el.data(collection: @collection, view: this)
```

I want to convert to javascript and keep as simple as possible. I thought this would work, but it seems to dislike my extend.

```
 Zoo.CollectionView = function() {

 }

 $.extend(Zoo.CollectionView.prototype, Zoo.View.prototype);

 Zoo.CollectionView.prototype._set_element_attributes = function() {
   this.$el.data({
     view: this
   });
   this.$el.addClass('collection');
   if (this.collection == null) {
     return;
   }
   this.$el.attr({
     'data-name': this.collection.collection_name
   });
   if (this.variant != null) {
     this.$el.attr({
       'data-variant': this.variant
     });
   }
   return this.$el.data({
     collection: this.collection,
     view: this
   });
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoffeeScript's `extends` is compatibly with Backbone's `extend` so you should be able to do this:

```
Zoo.CollectionView = Zoo.View.extend({
    _set_element_attributes: function() {
        // This part should be easy and it looks like you
        // have it in hand.
    }
});
```

I don't understand why you're trying to merge `Backbone.Model`'s prototype into `Zoo.CollectionView`'s:

```
$.extend(Zoo.CollectionView.prototype, Backbone.Model.prototype);
```

as your CoffeeScript doesn't do anything like that and models and views are very different things anyway.

Comment: That works perfectly and t'is wonderfully succinct. Thanks very much.